# How to get rtk telemetry topics for m600 pro with d rtk on Onboard SDK ros

Tags: dji-sdk

I recently integrated D rtk onto m600 pro.

DJI assistant 2 and DJI go app shows rtk is integrated and app also shows rtk data.

However in Onboard SDK ros, I’m not able to see any rtk based topics. Only regular topics like imu , gps are visible.

If the DJI app can show rtk data, why is api not able to detect rtk?

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Onboard-SDK-ROS-3.7\dji_sdk\src\modules\dji_sdk_node_publisher.cpp
[image: Publisher]

Comment: Hi Bruno,
It's part of dji sdk, rtk topics will be visible if rtk flag is true, which means sdk detects 5hz rtk data in subscription. I didn't understand what you were trying to convey.